# How to create a pointer array?

Tags: c

In my C program, I use the `strtok()` command to loop through all the tokens in a `string`. At each iteration it gives me a pointer to each token.

How can I store the pointers in an array such that the array is like the `argv` argument in the main function and can be used in the execvp command?

Comment: See *malloc* or *calloc* no it's not some drug names...

Comment: @ring0 - Do not worry - the OP is into fatty acids. Smells rather fishy to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by creating a vector of pointers to strings if you know how many toks you gonna get. Otherwise, you'll need to use dynamic structures.

If you know the size, something like this will work:

```
char **mytokens = malloc(MAXSIZE*sizeof(char*)); /*Allocation of a vector of pointers to strings*/

while(there_are_tokens && counter < MAXSIZE){
 mytokens[counter] = strtok(NULL,mystring);      /*Assuming you did strtok with delims before*/
 counter++;
}
```

For dynamic implementation you should go read some documentation/tutorials ([1](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node11.html)/[2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list)/[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_%28C_programming_language%29))

But a struct like this would be the way I'll do it:

```
typedef struct _tokens{
  char *token;
  struct _tokens *next;
}tokens;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *array[MAX_POINTERS];
char *str;


array[0] = str;
```

and if your str pointer will lose the momory in which it points or its content will change and you want to get a copy of it you can use `strdup`

```
array[0] = strdup(str);
```

and then when the `array[0]` became useless you have to free it with

```
free(array[0]);
```

Note: you can use `array` in the `execvp` command;

Comment: Since when can you do that without `strcpy()` ?

Comment: @Tim array is an array of pointer and not array of chars. array[0] contains the address of str pointer